# Oracle - Tree like query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, recursive-query, connect-by

there is a table: Groups

It has three columns: ID, NAME, PARENT

This would flow in the following way.

- Suppose there is a Group ELECTRONICS
- Under ELECTRONICS, there is MOBILE
- Under MOBILES there is SAMSUNG
- Under SAMSUNG there is GALAXY EDGE
- Under GALAXY EDGE there is 16GB and 8GB

the data in database would follow like:

```
ID             NAME                  PARENT
 1          ELECTRONICS               null
 2            MOBILE               ELECTRONICS
 3           SAMSUNG                 MOBILE
 4             16GB                  SAMSUNG
 5              8GB                  SAMSUNG
```

There may be N levels of hierarchy. I want to retrieve all the records of the last level. 
In this case, return 16GB and 8GB.

Comment: This is commonly solved with a recursive query using `START WITH` and `CONNECT BY`.  This one looks simple enough to use `START WITH PARENT IS NULL CONNECT BY PRIOR NAME = PARENT`.

Comment: Here is **Sql Server** Version convert to **oracle** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b7074/8

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach to such a problem is a recursive query. In Oracle this can be done using `connect by`.

However: to get all rows from the **last** level no recursive query is necessary.

Those are all rows that do not appear in the `parent` column:

```
select *
from Groups
where name not in (select parent
                   from groups g2
                   where g2.parent is not null);
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/df70d/1

---

A recursive query can be used to find e.g. all nodes *below* a certain category, e.g. if you want to find everything below SAMSUNG:

```
select *
from groups
start with name = 'SAMSUNG'
connect by prior name = parent;
```